# Python extensions with C: staticforward

Tags: python, c, forward-declaration, python-extensions

So I needed to use the code of the subprocess module to add some functionality I needed. When I was trying to compile the _subprocess.c file, it gives this error message:

`Error  1   error C2086: 'PyTypeObject sp_handle_type' : redefinition`

This is the code part which is relevant from `_subprocess.c` file:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    HANDLE handle;
} sp_handle_object;

staticforward PyTypeObject sp_handle_type;

static PyObject*
sp_handle_new(HANDLE handle)
{
    sp_handle_object* self;

    self = PyObject_NEW(sp_handle_object, &sp_handle_type);
    if (self == NULL)
        return NULL;

    self->handle = handle;

    return (PyObject*)self;
}

#if defined(MS_WIN32) && !defined(MS_WIN64)
#define HANDLE_TO_PYNUM(handle) PyInt_FromLong((long) handle)
#define PY_HANDLE_PARAM "l"
#else
#define HANDLE_TO_PYNUM(handle) PyLong_FromLongLong((long long) handle)
#define PY_HANDLE_PARAM "L"
#endif

static PyObject*
sp_handle_detach(sp_handle_object* self, PyObject* args)
{
    HANDLE handle;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, ":Detach"))
        return NULL;

    handle = self->handle;

    self->handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    /* note: return the current handle, as an integer */
    return HANDLE_TO_PYNUM(handle);
}

static PyObject*
sp_handle_close(sp_handle_object* self, PyObject* args)
{
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, ":Close"))
        return NULL;

    if (self->handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        CloseHandle(self->handle);
        self->handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

static void
sp_handle_dealloc(sp_handle_object* self)
{
    if (self->handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        CloseHandle(self->handle);
    PyObject_FREE(self);
}

static PyMethodDef sp_handle_methods[] = {
    { "Detach", (PyCFunction)sp_handle_detach, METH_VARARGS },
    { "Close", (PyCFunction)sp_handle_close, METH_VARARGS },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

static PyObject*
sp_handle_getattr(sp_handle_object* self, char* name)
{
    return Py_FindMethod(sp_handle_methods, (PyObject*)self, name);
}

static PyObject*
sp_handle_as_int(sp_handle_object* self)
{
    return HANDLE_TO_PYNUM(self->handle);
}

static PyNumberMethods sp_handle_as_number;

statichere PyTypeObject sp_handle_type = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                                  /*ob_size*/
    "_subprocess_handle", sizeof(sp_handle_object), 0,
    (destructor)sp_handle_dealloc, /*tp_dealloc*/
    0, /*tp_print*/
    (getattrfunc)sp_handle_getattr,/*tp_getattr*/
    0,                                  /*tp_setattr*/
    0,                                  /*tp_compare*/
    0,                                  /*tp_repr*/
    &sp_handle_as_number,               /*tp_as_number */
    0,                                  /*tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                  /*tp_as_mapping */
    0                                   /*tp_hash*/
};`
```

Also I've found that:

```
#define staticforward static
#define statichere static
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
Btw (I'm not sure if it's relevant), I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 to compile this file.

Answer (score 1):

**Notes**:

- I'm talking about *Python 2.7* here (since in newer versions, the *subprocess* module no longer has an own *C* implementation for *Win*)
- *Python 2.7* is built (officially) using *VStudio2008 (9.0)* according to [[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers). Building it with a newer (or better: different) version, might yield some other (and harder to find) errors. For example, when I built it with *VStudio 2010 (10.0)* (I used the built version to run a complex set of (*.py**) scripts), I had some trouble at *runtime* when encountering socket related errors because of some mismatches between *errno* and *WSA** codes, that were changed between the 2 versions

When I tested, I couldn't understand why you encountered the issue and I didn't, then for a while I forgot about it, then when you posted the last comment, it started eating me alive again. As I said I was able to successfully compile the file using *VStudio 2010 / 2013*.

Trying to compile the same (this was only an assumption) code with different results -> the *way* that code is compiled might differ. Therefore, I started investigating for other possible definition places for *staticforward* and *statichere* (besides lines *878* / *879* of *object.h*) due to conditional macros: ***#if***, ***#ifdef***, ... . But, I couldn't find any. So, I added some simpler statements:

```c
staticforward int i;
statichere int i = 2;
```

then, I manually replaced the defines:

```c
static int i;
static int i = 2;
```

in *_subprocess.c* (by coincidence, I added them at line *#137* - just before `statichere PyTypeObject sp_handle_type = {` - fact that prevented me to figure out the problem at this point), and it still compiled!!!

Next step, I pasted the above lines in another solution that I had open (in a *.cpp* source file), and I was able to reproduce the error. So, I payed more attention to the compiler flags (I copy/pasted from the *x86 Debug* settings of the projects automatically converted by *VStudio* from the ones found in the *PCbuild* folder):

- *VStudio 2013*

  > ```bat
  > /GS
  > /analyze-
  > /W3
  > /Gy
  > /Zc:wchar_t
  > /I"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\Python"
  > /I"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\Modules\zlib"
  > /I"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\Include"
  > /I"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\PC"
  > /Zi
  > /Gm-
  > /Od
  > /Fd"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\pythoncore\vc120.pdb"
  > /fp:precise
  > /D "_USRDLL"
  > /D "Py_BUILD_CORE"
  > /D "Py_ENABLE_SHARED"
  > /D "MS_DLL_ID=\"2.7-32\""
  > /D "WIN32"
  > /D "_WIN32"
  > /D "_DEBUG"
  > /D "_WINDLL"
  > /errorReport:prompt
  > /GF
  > /WX-
  > /Zc:forScope
  > /Gd
  > /Oy-
  > /Oi
  > /MDd
  > /Fa"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\pythoncore\"
  > /nologo
  > /Fo"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\pythoncore\"
  > /Fp"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.11-vs2k13\PCbuild\obj\win32_Debug\pythoncore\python27_d.pch"
  > ```
- *VStudio 2010*

  > ```bat
  > /I"..\Python"
  > /I"..\Modules\zlib"
  > /I"..\Include"
  > /I"..\PC"
  > /Zi
  > /nologo
  > /W3
  > /WX-
  > /Od
  > /Oy-
  > /D "_USRDLL"
  > /D "Py_BUILD_CORE"
  > /D "Py_ENABLE_SHARED"
  > /D "WIN32"
  > /D "_DEBUG"
  > /D "_WIN32"
  > /D "_WINDLL"
  > /GF
  > /Gm-
  > /MDd
  > /GS
  > /Gy
  > /fp:precise
  > /Zc:wchar_t
  > /Zc:forScope
  > /Fp"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.10-vcbuild\PCbuild\Win32-temp-Debug\pythoncore\pythoncore.pch"
  > /Fa"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.10-vcbuild\PCbuild\Win32-temp-Debug\pythoncore\"
  > /Fo"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.10-vcbuild\PCbuild\Win32-temp-Debug\pythoncore\"
  > /Fd"E:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\OPSWpython27\src\Python-2.7.10-vcbuild\PCbuild\Win32-temp-Debug\pythoncore\vc100.pdb"
  > /Gd
  > /analyze-
  > /errorReport:queue
  > ```

and then it struck me: It's the **way of how the file is compiled: *C* vs. *C++*** (the [[MS.Docs]: /Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP (Specify Source File Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/032xwy55(v=vs.120)) flag). Of course, compiling *_subprocess.c* as *C++* would spit your error.

Check [[SO]: Creating a dynamically allocated struct with a 2D dynamically allocated string (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918914/creating-a-dynamically-allocated-struct-with-a-2d-dynamically-allocated-string/41922266#41922266), for (a little bit) more details, and how the same mistake triggered very different errors.

Comment: Does this qualify as an answer to your question?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found an answer.

It turns out that the definition of `staticforward` should have been `extern` instead of `static`. My compiler didn't know how to handle it. I guess in other compilers it works ok.

Comment: This file (as all others) should compile, _OOTB_.  I've tried a couple of  combinations (_VC2k10_ vs _Py27_ as an eg.), but wasn't able to reproduce the issue. You should probably (look for dups), and close the issue. __Anyway , I don't see this as a solution.__

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, you can't define a static variable twice. staticforward and statichere were both defiend as "static" so in fact, the error is legit.
Changing staticforward to `extern` tells the compiler that the variable will be defined later.

Comment: _"In Visual Studio 2013, you can't define a static variable twice. staticforward and statichere were both defeend as 'static' so in fact, the error is legit"_. This couldn't be more __wrong__. In any _VStudio_ (or any _VS_, or _C_) compiler version, `static` means that the varables are only visible in the complation unit (_c_ / _c++_ file). Please check the internet (_Google_, _MSDN_, _Wiki_ ,... and tons of others) for details.

Comment: It's kind of hillarous that (you think that) a whole community did such a mistake (naming `staticforward`(`staic`) but meaning `extern`) and in 2017 __you__  were the one who found it. BTW, on my box, _Py2.7.10_ compiles _OOTB_ using _VS2k13_....now, the question: what did you do to _subprocess.c_ (or one of the headers included) to mess things up so bad?

Comment: What were you really trying to do?

Comment: @CristiFati I extended the subrocess module to support spawning processes with a given NUMA node and affinity mask (like in the windows 'start' command).