# Creating a dynamically allocated struct with a 2D dynamically allocated string

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct

I'm trying to scan in a grid of letters. `cases` is the number of letter grids and `r`, `c` are for number of rows and columns of each grid.  I figured I could create an array of structs with 2D arrays inside.  I've been working on this for a few hours now and it's still giving me problems:

- Warnings:

  - *Warning C4477* (Line 12) - *‘scanf_s’ : format string ‘%s’ requires an argument of type ‘char*’, but variadic argument 1 has type ‘int’*
  - *Warning C4473* (Line 12) - *‘scanf_s’ : not enough arguments passed for format string*
- Errors:

  - [Compiler Error C2274](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2274)&rd=true)
  - [Compiler Error C2461](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2461)&rd=true)

The code:

```
scanf_s("%d", &cases);
struct grid { 
    char **grid; 
};
struct grid *grids = (struct grid*)malloc(cases * sizeof(struct grid));

for (i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
    scanf_s("%d %d", &r, &c);
    grids[i].grid = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * r);
    for (k = 0; k < r; k++) {
        grids[i].grid[k] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (c+1));
        scanf_s("%s", grids[i].grid[k], (c+1));
    }           
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", grids[i].grid[k]);` → `scanf_s("%s", grids[i].grid[k], c + 1);`. [`scanf_s` requires a third argument for `%s`, `%c` etc denoting the maximum size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx). Also, it is recommended to [avoid casting `malloc`'s return value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3049655)

Comment: The first compiler mistake could be caused by giving your `struct grid` a field named `grid` ; i've never tried, but i doubt it's allowed.

Comment: I thought malloc's return value is void and that's why you always have to cast it?

Comment: @m.raynal: There is no problem with that.

Comment: No, the call to malloc automatically promotes the pointer to the right type.
@keine Lust, thanks, i'll know, but it definitly seems to me being a bad habit a source of confusion.

Comment: Why are you not checking result of `scanf_s()`?

Comment: How do you mean checking result?  My code will not compile because of the lines above.

Comment: The exact *lines* where those linked errors happen should be noted in the posted source code, and the full text of the error messages should *always* be included *verbatim* in questions asking about error messages.

Comment: What is terminal output?

Comment: Post whatever error message you are getting, so that we can get a better understanding of the problem. It compiled and ran without any errors in my Ubuntu system (of course I replaced `scanf_s()` with `scanf()`).

Comment: "*constructor syntax missing formal parameters*" this heavily sounds like C++. Are you sure you are using a C compiler?

Comment: So please, *what* are the lines 3, 9, and 12? :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak a little bit the code in the question, also to add some missing parts (that should have also been provided, btw), to get a compilable (using *VStudio2010*) piece.

*main00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct grid { 
    char **grid; 
};


int main() {
    int cases, r, c, k, i;
    struct grid *grids;

    scanf_s("%d", &cases);
    grids = (struct grid*)malloc(cases * sizeof(struct grid));

    for (i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d %d", &r, &c);
        grids[i].grid = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * r);
        for (k = 0; k < r; k++) {
            grids[i].grid[k] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (c + 1));
            scanf_s("%s", grids[i].grid[k], (c + 1));
        }           
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- You were compiling the code as *C++* (as @alk noticed), and this is what completely threw you off course. In order to fix that either:

  - Set your file extension to **.c** (and you can leave the *VStudio* defaults in term of compilation; that way it will compile each source file using the appropriate compiler based on its extension)
  - **Explicitly** compile the source file as *C*. You can set that from *VStudio Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As*, and choosing *Compile as C Code*. For more info, visit [[MS.Docs]: /Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP (Specify Source File Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/032xwy55(v=vs.100)). Personally, I think that the former option is more straightforward
- Move the variable declarations **before** any statements (I think this might have been a candidate for setting the *C++* compiler). This was a restriction for older *C* standards (I doubt that it still stands), but (*VStudio 2010*) *C* compiler still enforces it (at least by default)

Comment: Thank you CristiFati.  That was the problem.  When I switched it over to a .c file it did run but I got a whole new line of problems with it not showing any new errors and crashing.  It would not even take any new changes so  I just switched to Codeblocks.  I don't think I have a deep enough knowledge to troubleshoot VS right now.

Comment: Then would you please mark the answer as a solution, so it's clear that it solves the problem?