# Simstring (python) installation in windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, python-3.x, swig

I am trying to install simstring python wrapper in windows by https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/simstring. For linux it works fine but for windows it is giving me error while installing.

```
    D:\Users\source\repos>python setup.py install
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_simstring' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" /EHsc /Tpexport.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\export.obj
    export.cpp
    export.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iconv.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

After this I included iconv.h in the project. But now it shows different error.

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_simstring' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" /EHsc /Tpexport.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\export.obj
export.cpp
d:\users\aki\source\repos\simstring\cdbpp.h(101): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
export.cpp(37): error C2664: 'size_t libiconv(libiconv_t,const char **,size_t *,char **,size_t *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char **' to 'const char **'
export.cpp(37): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
export.cpp(140): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool iconv_convert<std::string,std::wstring>(libiconv_t,const source_type &,destination_type &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            source_type=std::string,
            destination_type=std::wstring
        ]
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: *iconv* is *Ux* based. Did you install the port for *Win*?

Comment: Yes, i did install it for windows by following http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ground notes**:

- I managed to go with the build process but I got stuck at one point. I created [[SO]: Compile error for (char based) STL (stream) containers in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48716223/4788546) (I spent quite some time on that issue). I got that working somehow, but there were other (similar?) errors when trying to build *SimString*, so I had to strip some (*Nix* based) code (that didn't compile) out
- *SimString* is written in *C++*. When *C++* (*C*) code is built, the result is *PE* or *Portable Executable* (*.exe*, *.dll*). Check [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546) for more details regarding how code gets transformed. When dealing with an *.exe* that depends on (loads) *.dll*s, there are certain restrictions:

  - The *.exe* (in this case *python.exe*)'s architecture (*032bit* (*pc032*) *vs.* *064bit* (*pc064*) or (*x86* *vs.* *x64* (or *AMD64*))) must match the one of any *.dll* that it loads (and other *.dll* that a loaded *.dll* loads, and so on), so all the *dll*s in the dependency tree, otherwise the *.dll* won't load
  - The platform (*Debug* *vs.* *Release*) should match in some cases. Here's what could happen if it didn't: [[SO]: When using fstream in a library I get linker errors in the executable (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558269/4788546), but I don't think that we are in that situation
  - The build tools should also match in some (other) cases. Examples:

    - Compiler type ([[SO]: Python extensions with C: staticforward (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42793268/4788546))
    - The *CRT runtime* ([[SO]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546))
    - The *CRT runtime* **version** is important in our case. Check [[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) for compatibilities between *Python* and *VStudio* versions. Note that this only applies for *Python* versions downloaded and installed (if you built your *Python* from sources, then you should use the same build tool - but I guess it's not the case here)

      - I see you are using *VStudio 2017*, so the compatible versions are *Python 3.5* and *Python 3.6* <sup>**1**</sup>. I have ~10 *Python* installations on my machine (some installed, some built by me - with different compiler; most of them are *pc064*, I also have some *VEnv*s, but that shouldn't make any difference). I also have 5 *VStudio* versions installed, in my case, *setup.py* automatically selects *VStudio 2015* (but it's ok, since as *VStudio 2017* it has compiler **v14.0**)
  - *SimString* depends on *LibIconv* which also comes as a *.dll* (actually there are more, but we only care about one). Checking the *.dll* (see below) with [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com) reveals that it's *x86* (*pc032*) <sup>**2**</sup>. That means that either:

    - *Python* *032bit* (*x86*) should be used. This is the variant that I'm going to go with. From <sup>**1**</sup> and <sup>**2**</sup>, the only available version on my machine is *Python 3.6 pc032* (*Python 3.5* is my version of choice, I also have it in *032bit* format, but I messed it up and didn't reinstall it)
    - Build *LibIconv* from source, and get rid of restriction <sup>**2**</sup>. But, that could take time, and it's outside the scope of the current question. If there will be a question about building it, I'll take some time and give it a shot, as I enjoy that kind of tasks ([[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469099/4788546))

**Walkthrough**:

- Create a *dir* and *CD* to it (should be empty). This will be the *%ROOT_DIR%*, and all the paths that I'm going to use will be relative to it (except of course for absolute ones), and this will be the default *dir* (when unspecified)
- Download *SimString* sources ([[GitHub]: Georgetown-IR-Lab/simstring - simstring-master.zip](https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/simstring/archive/master.zip))
- Unzip the archive - it will do it in a *dir* *simstring-master* (will be automatically created)
- Create a *dir* *libiconv*. Inside it, download:

  1. [[SourceForge]: gnuwin32/GnuWin - libiconv-1.9.2-1-lib.zip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/libiconv-lib-zip.php)
  2. [[SourceForge]: gnuwin32/GnuWin - libiconv-1.9.2-1-bin.zip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/libiconv-bin-zip.php)
  3. Extract needed stuff from these files:

     - From *#1.*:

       - *include* *dir* - used at compile phase
       - *lib* *dir* - used at link phase
       - Both phases are performed by *setup.py* (below)
     - From *#2.*:

       - *bin* *dir* - used at runtime (when using (importing) the module)
- *CD* to the *simstring-master* *dir*. To build the extension, I'm using *setup.py*'s *build_ext* command (invoked recursively by *install* - as seen in your output): [[Python 3.Docs]: distutils.command.build_ext - Build any extensions in a package](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.build_ext)
- Running *build_ext*, will yield your error:

  > ```
  > export.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iconv.h': No such file or directory
  > ```

  That is because *Python* build system doesn't know what we did (in the *libiconv* dir). To let it know, pass the:

  1. ***-I*** (*--include-dirs*) - will be translated to [[MS.Docs]: /I (Additional include directories)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2015)
  2. ***-L*** (*--library-dirs*) - will be translated to [[MS.Docs]: /LIBPATH (Additional Libpath)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/libpath-additional-libpath?view=vs-2015)
  3. ***-l*** (*--libraries*) - will be translated to [[MS.Docs]: LINK Input Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/link-input-files?view=vs-2015)

  flags (`python setup.py build_ext --help` will display all of them). For now, don't pass *#2.* and *#3.* because we won't get to the link phase (where they are required):

  > ```bat
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x86_test\Scripts\python.exe" setup.py build_ext -I"../libiconv/include"
  > running build_ext
  > building '_simstring' extension
  > C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -I../libiconv/include -Ic:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\include -Ic:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\include "-IC:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" /EHsc /Tpexport.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\export.obj
  > export.cpp
  > export.cpp(112): warning C4297: 'writer::~writer': function assumed not to throw an exception but does
  > export.cpp(112): note: destructor or deallocator has a (possibly implicit) non-throwing exception specification
  > export.cpp(126): warning C4297: 'writer::~writer': function assumed not to throw an exception but does
  > export.cpp(126): note: destructor or deallocator has a (possibly implicit) non-throwing exception specification
  > export.cpp(37): error C2664: 'size_t libiconv(libiconv_t,const char **,size_t *,char **,size_t *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char **' to 'const char **'
  > export.cpp(37): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
  > export.cpp(140): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool iconv_convert<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::wstring>(libiconv_t,const source_type &,destination_type &)' being compiled
  > with
  > [
  >     source_type=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
  >     destination_type=std::wstring
  > ]
  > error: command 'C:\\Install\\x86\\Microsoft\\Visual Studio Community\\2015\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  > ```
- Things to do (found out fixing the errors one by one, only *export.cpp* required changes):

  1. `#define ICONV_CONST const` (*cl.exe* doesn't automatically cast *const*ness)
  2. `#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 2`  (as `sizeof(wchar_t)` is ***2***)
  3. Strip out the code that doesn't compile (that I talked about at the beginning): *STL* containers with *4 byte* *char*s don't compile on *Win*, wanted to fix the code, and when *Win* will support such *char*s, the code will compile *OOTB*, but I wasn't able to, so I had to do whatever was done for *OSX*. As a consequence, `#ifdef __APPLE__` should be replaced by `#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(WIN32)` (5 occurrences)

  Note that *#1.* and *#2.* could (should) be done either by cmdline (***-D*** flag, but I wasn't able to specify a value for a defined flag), or in *setup.py* (so they are only defined once even if they need to be declared in lots of files), but I didn't spend too much time on it, so I'm replacing them directly in the source code.

  Either apply the changes manually, either save:

  ```diff
  --- export.cpp.orig 2016-11-30 18:53:32.000000000 +0200
  +++ export.cpp  2018-02-14 13:36:31.317953200 +0200
  @@ -19,9 +19,18 @@
   #endif/*USE_LIBICONV_GNU*/

   #ifndef ICONV_CONST
  +#if defined (WIN32)
  +#define ICONV_CONST const
  +#else
   #define ICONV_CONST
  +#endif
   #endif/*ICONV_CONST*/

  +#if defined (WIN32)
  +#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 2
  +#endif
  +
  +
   template <class source_type, class destination_type>
   bool iconv_convert(iconv_t cd, const source_type& src, destination_type& dst)
   {
  @@ -269,7 +278,7 @@
       iconv_close(bwd);
   }

  -#ifdef __APPLE__
  +#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(WIN32)
   #include <cassert>
   #endif

  @@ -283,7 +292,7 @@
           retrieve_thru(dbr, query, this->measure, this->threshold, std::back_inserter(ret));
           break;
       case 2:
  -#ifdef __APPLE__
  +#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(WIN32)
   #if __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ == 2
           retrieve_iconv<wchar_t>(dbr, query, UTF16, this->measure, this->threshold, std::back_inserter(ret));
   #else
  @@ -294,7 +303,7 @@
   #endif
           break;
       case 4:
  -#ifdef __APPLE__
  +#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(WIN32)
   #if __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ == 4
           retrieve_iconv<wchar_t>(dbr, query, UTF32, this->measure, this->threshold, std::back_inserter(ret));
   #else
  @@ -317,7 +326,7 @@
           std::string qstr = query;
           return dbr.check(qstr, translate_measure(this->measure), this->threshold);
       } else if (dbr.char_size() == 2) {
  -#ifdef __APPLE__
  +#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(WIN32)
   #if __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ == 2
           std::basic_string<wchar_t> qstr;
   #else
  @@ -333,7 +342,7 @@
           iconv_close(fwd);
           return dbr.check(qstr, translate_measure(this->measure), this->threshold);
       } else if (dbr.char_size() == 4) {
  -#ifdef __APPLE__
  +#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(WIN32)
   #if __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ == 4
           std::basic_string<wchar_t> qstr;
   #else
  ```

  as *simstring_win.diff*. That is a *diff*. See [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *UTRunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out).
  I also submitted this patch to **[[GitHub]: Georgetown-IR-Lab/simstring - Support for Win](https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/simstring/pull/2)**, and **it was merged today** (*180222*).

  > ```bat
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>"c:\Install\x64\Cygwin\Cygwin\AllVers\bin\patch.exe" -i "../simstring_win.diff"
  > patching file export.cpp
  >
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>rem Looking at export.cpp content, you'll notice the changes
  >
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x86_test\Scripts\python.exe" setup.py build_ext  -I"../libiconv/include" -L"../libiconv/lib" -llibiconv
  > running build_ext
  > building '_simstring' extension
  > C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -I../libiconv/include -Ic:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\include -Ic:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\include "-IC:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" /EHsc /Tpexport.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\export.obj
  > export.cpp
  > export.cpp(121): warning C4297: 'writer::~writer': function assumed not to throw an exception but does
  > export.cpp(121): note: destructor or deallocator has a (possibly implicit) non-throwing exception specification
  > export.cpp(135): warning C4297: 'writer::~writer': function assumed not to throw an exception but does
  > export.cpp(135): note: destructor or deallocator has a (possibly implicit) non-throwing exception specification
  > C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -I../libiconv/include -Ic:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\include -Ic:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\include "-IC:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" /EHsc /Tpexport_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\export_wrap.obj
  > export_wrap.cpp
  > C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\Libs /LIBPATH:../libiconv/lib /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x86_test\libs /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x86_test\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\ATLMFC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x86" libiconv.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__simstring build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\export.obj build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\export_wrap.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\_simstring.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_simstring.cp36-win32.lib
  >    Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_simstring.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_simstring.cp36-win32.exp
  > Generating code
  > Finished generating code
  >
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>dir /b "build\lib.win32-3.6"
  > _simstring.cp36-win32.pyd
  > ```
- Finally, it built. the *.pyd* is just a *.dll*. This is how it looks like in *Dependency Walker*:

  [image: _simstring.pyd]
- Let's try to see if we can use it:

  > ```bat
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x86_test\Scripts\python.exe" sample.py
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master\simstring.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
  >     fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_simstring', [dirname(__file__)])
  >   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x86_test\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
  >     raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
  > ImportError: No module named '_simstring'
  >
  > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  >
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "sample.py", line 3, in <module>
  >     import simstring
  >   File "E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master\simstring.py", line 28, in <module>
  >     _simstring = swig_import_helper()
  >   File "E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master\simstring.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
  >     import _simstring
  > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_simstring'
  > ```

  That is because when importing *SimString*, which in turn imports *_simstring* (the *.pyd*), *Python* doesn't find it. To fix this:

  - Add the *.pyd* path to *%PYTHONPATH%*
  - As seen in the *pic*, the *.pyd* depends on *libiconv2.dll*, so the *OS* must know where to look for it. Simplest way is to add its path to *%PATH%* ([[MS.Docs]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order))

  > ```
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;build\lib.win32-3.6
  >
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>set PATH=%PATH%;..\libiconv\bin
  >
  > (py36x86_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048528041\simstring-master>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x86_test\Scripts\python.exe" sample.py
  > ('Barack Hussein Obama II',)
  > ('James Gordon Brown',)
  > ()
  > ('Barack Hussein Obama II',)
  > ```

**Final notes**:

- There is some output from the module, it's identical to the one on *Nix* (*Ubuntu*) (where I also built it - there I encountered no problem), I'm not sure whether it's *semantically* correct or not
- I didn't run *setup.py*'s ***install*** command (and I'm not gonna), one thing that I can think of that could go wrong (although I'm not sure it will), is not copying / including *libiconv2.dll* into the *.whl*. If so, you'll probably need to modify *setup.py* (changes should be minor)

Comment: I really encourage you to submit PR as I was in touch with one of the contributor (https://github.com/soldni) and he is willing to accept PR.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Done: https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/simstring/pull/2.

Answer (score 1):

Besides my other response about building under Cygwin, I've made a few other changes to allow this to build and install seamlessly with Windows using Anaconda.  Turns out conda can install iconv very easily.

Much of this is based on the work that ChristiFati added in this thread, this change intends to simplify the steps and potential installation.

<s>This change currently exists in my own fork.  Steps are in the README here.  I have also submitted a Pull Request for this.</s>

UPDATE: This pull request has now been taken into the Georgetown repo so you can get it herre:
https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/simstring

As a side note, one of the motivations for doing this is making this repo easier to set up: https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/QuickUMLS

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build that repo under Cygwin.  The packages libiconv-devel and python3-devel both need to be installed.

After that, I had one more change that I made to ensure that libiconv would be available for Windows build.  I made that single commit here:

https://github.com/burgersmoke/simstring